# Excel with NPOI: Get the style (backgroundcolor) of a Cell

Tags: c#, excel, npoi

I am using NPOI to parse an Excel-File with C# (VS 2013). I want to get the backgroundcolor of a cell and I am doing this:

```
IEnumerator rows = sheet.GetRowEnumerator();

while (rows.MoveNext())
{
    IRow row = (IRow)rows.Current;

    foreach (ICell cell in row.Cells)
    {
        if (cell.CellStyle.FillBackgroundColor == 64)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Problem is, that regardless of the background-color of the cell (yellow, green, no color at all), the value of FillBackgroundColor ist always 64. So it seems, that isn't the place, where the color is stored. How do I get it then?

Edith says: The cell.CellStyle.Index property differs for all cells

Thanks in advance, 
Frank

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is, that in Excel the CellStyle.FillBackgroundColor is not the FillColor of the Cell. To check it, first make sure it has a Fill at all (CellStyle.FillPattern) and then check the CellStyle.FillForegroundColorColor property. f.e.

```
if (cell.CellStyle.FillPattern == FillPattern.SolidForeground)
   byte[] cellBackground = cell.CellStyle.FillForegroundColorColor.RGB;
```

Comment: You may have to cast it based on the type of spreadsheet file.
((XSSFCellStyle)row.GetCell(j).CellStyle).FillForegroundXSSFColor.RGB;

Got it by checking the tests at:
https://github.com/nissl-lab/npoi/blob/6ae411b29e5f2f612c0ba1da4e8c4272afeba029/testcases/ooxml/XSSF/UserModel/TestXSSFColor.cs